# Deselecting a column by name

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe, slice

Is there a way to select all columns of a data frame except a column that has a particular name.

It would be the analog of `df[, -1]`, except using the column name instead of the index?

Comment: I want to offer [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) as an alternative to data.frame. It provides better selection possibilities.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can do this using vector subsetting. First, create a dummy data set:

```
R> dd = data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 1:3, C=1:3, D=1:3)
```

Then use the `!` operator to reverse the selection:

```
R> dd[ ,!(colnames(dd) == "A")]

  B C D
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
```

Alternatively, you could have:

- A slightly shorter version (courtesy of @Tomas):

  ```
  dd[ , names(dd) != "A"]
  ```
- To cope with multiple columns (courtesy of @Tyler)

  ```
  dd[ ,!(colnames(dd) %in% c("A", "B"))]
  ```

Comment: You don't need the extra comma, you can subset more directly:

`dd[names(dd) != "A"]`

Answer (score 10):

One could use the `which()` function to identify the column to be eliminated.

```
dd <- data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 1:5, C=1:5)

dd[, -which(names(dd) == "A")]
```

or positively

```
dd[, which(names(dd) != "A")]
```

However, if there is no column named "A", you would get a data frame with 0 columns and `nrow(dd)` rows. So it would be good to check for the existence of a column named "A".

```
if(any(names(dd) == "A")) {
  dd[, which(names(dd) != "A")]
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The `subset` function already allows this type of syntax, from the examples on the help page:

```
subset(airquality, Day == 1, select = -Temp)
```

Answer (score 5):

**remove A and C**

#### `base` solution

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 1:3, C=1:3, D=1:3)

df[,c("A","C")]<-NULL
```

#### `data.table` solution

```
dt <- data.table(A = 1:3, B = 1:3, C=1:3, D=1:3)

#    A B C D
# 1: 1 1 1 1
# 2: 2 2 2 2
# 3: 3 3 3 3

dt[,c("A","C"):=NULL]

#   B D
#1: 1 1
#2: 2 2
#3: 3 3
```

Answer (score 4):

For deselecting multiple columns you can use the dplyr package. As an example:

```
dd = data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 1:3, C=1:3, D=1:3)

library(dplyr)
newdd <- select(dd, -A,-C)
```

this is another way besides what @csgillespie suggested.